# Remote Access to Web Service (Microsoft Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have tried to create a hello world Web Service using visual studio 2008, and i got this here's the address

```
http://localhost:49398/Service1.asmx
```

It seems no problem when i access and consume this web service locally, but when i try to access this web service using other computer, it fails.
I have tried several address by guessing but it seems no luck.

```
http://1.2.3.4/Service1.asmx
http://1.2.3.4:49398/Service1.asmx
```

I have no clue at all on what I should do so that I can access to it.
Your help is pretty much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have no clue on whether its a asmx or WCF, but i started this by
new project->web->asp.net web service application-> CTL + F5 to compile it

this is a tutorial from www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOqEKpYbTzw

Could you suggest the tutorial on how to host it to IIS?

Comment: Hi is this a wcf web service or a asmx?

Comment: Did you have hosted this Service on IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development web server ( Cassini ) doesn't support remote access, so you need to use IIS.

You will also need to open the port in any firewall you're using.

The url from a remote machine would be:

```
http://1.2.3.4:49398/Service1.asmx
```